# how to output form values to alert JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Need your help! I hope you will help me..
For example, I have a form that consists of: First Name, Last Name, Email, a drop-down list and 8 divs with lengths of time (when you click on any color changed). When you press the submission button, an alert displays the information of the values that the user entered.
Sample message:
"Name Surname" booked an audition for the film "Spider-Man" for "Leading Role." We are waiting for you in "17: 00-18: 00". Detailed information sent to your "email"
I'm trying to do it in different ways, but nothing comes out

**CSS**

```
<style>
        .demo {
              border: 1px solid black;
              width: 100px;
              text-align: center;
              float: left;
              margin: 10px;
        }

       .selected {
              background-color:blue;
              border: 1px solid black;
              width: 100px;
              text-align: center;
              float: left;
              margin: 10px;
        }

        .reserved {
              background-color:red;
              border: 1px solid black;
              width: 100px;
              text-align: center;
              float: left;
              margin: 10px;
        }            

  </style>
```

**HTML**

```
<body>

  <form action="" name="formName" onsubmit="complete(this)">
        <label for="firstName">Firstname : </label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="firstName" placeholder="Enter your firstname" required>
        <br>
        <br>
        <label for="lastName">Lastname : </label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="lastName" placeholder="Enter your lastname" required>
        <br>
        <br>
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" id="email">

        <label for="movie">Movie</label>
        <select name="movie" id="movie">
              <option value=""></option>
              <option value="Spider man">Spiderman</option>
              <option value="Iron man">Ironman</option>
              <option value="Super man">Superman</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <br>
        <label for="movie_role">Role in the movie</label>
        <select name="role" id="movie_role">
              <option value=""></option>
              <option value="main">the main role</option>
              <option value="stuntman">stuntman</option>
              <option value="extras">extras</option>
              <option value="supporting role">supporting role</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <br>
        <div onclick="myFunction()" class="demo">
              <p>9:00 - 10:00</p>
        </div>

        <div onclick="myFunction()" class="demo">
              <p>10:00 - 11:00</p>
        </div>

        <div onclick="myFunction()" class="demo">
              <p>11:00 - 12:00</p>
        </div>

        <div onclick="myFunction()" class="demo">
              <p>12:00 - 13:00</p>
        </div>

        <div onclick="myFunction()" class="demo">
              <p>14:00 - 15:00</p>
        </div>
        <div  onclick="myFunction()" class="demo">
              <p>15:00 - 16:00</p>
        </div>
        <div  onclick="myFunction()" class="demo">
              <p>16:00 - 17:00</p>
        </div>
        <div onclick="myFunction()" class="demo">
              <p>17:00 - 18:00</p>
        </div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" onclick="">
  </form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
    <script>

      var fName = document.getElementById("firstName").value;
      var lName = document.getElementById("lastName").value;

      var movieList = document.getElementById("movie");
      var selectedMovie = movieList.options[movieList.selectedIndex].text;



//    function myFunction() {
//       if(this.className != "selected" && this.className != "reserved") {
//                   this.className = "selected";
//                   //alert ("Da vy zdes !");
//             } else if (this.className == "selected" && this.className != "reserved") {
//                   this.className = "selected";
//                   var r = confirm("You have booked time. If you change your mind click 'cancel'!");

//                   if (r == true) {
//                         alert("Thank you");
//                         this.className = "selected";
//                   } else {
//                         this.className = "reserved";
//                         alert("You canceled your reservation!");
//                   }


//             } else if (this.className == "reserved") {
//                   alert("This time is taken!");
//             }

//       }

      /*
      function myFunction() {
      if(document.getElementById("demo").style.background != "blue" && document.getElementsById("demo").style.background != "red") {
                  document.getElementById("demo").style.background = "blue";
            } else if (document.getElementById("demo").style.background = "blue" && document.getElementById(
                        "demo").style.background != "red") {
                  var r = confirm("You have booked time. If you change your mind click 'cancel'!");
                  if (r == true) {
                        alert("Thank you")
                  } else {
                        document.getElementById("demo").style.background = "white";
                        alert("You canceled your reservation!")
                  }


            } else if (document.getElementsByClassName("demo").style.background = "red") {
                  alert("This time is taken!");
            }

      }
      */
</script>
```

Comment: You will need a third party library like JQuery UI to open a modal popup. Like this [dialog](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/).

Comment: Hello everyone!

Comment: I need the usual classic alert with form values, but I don't know how to make a function correctly

Comment: The DOM alert function only shows vanilla text.  No HTML, No form input tag, just text.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. You want to alert form element values? They are strings, you'd alert them the same way you have other alerts.  On related note, you have problems in your code that are unrelated to the alert or the form, such as using assignment where you mean to use an equality check.

Comment: Why don't you just create a div element, which will be hidden, and when user presses submit, the element shows up with all the data you need, and then when user clicks okay / cancel (or whatever it is), make it disappear again ? Why use an alert at all ?

Answer (score -1):

You need a function inside "" for the onclick event. For example:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="myFunction()">
<script>
function myFunction() {
var fName = document.getElementById("firstName").value;
var lName = document.getElementById("lastName").value;
alert(fName + lName); //this will alert the first name and the last name.
}
</script>
```

You can do similar with the others.

Comment: That doesn't answer the need expressed in the question.

Comment: Good. But what should I do with div elements, how can I get information from them and repaint them in a different color?

Comment: If you want to interact with the div elements it is better to you the jquery library. You can access the elements in this way:

Comment: I'd love to do it, but I'm currently trying to figure out Javascript

Comment: If you want to interact with the div elements it is better to you the jquery library. You can access the elements in this way:
var k=" ";
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".demo").click(function() {
        k=$(this).find('p').value; // this is the div you've clicked and the find //method find the paragraf that is inside the div

Comment: If I am getting you rigth you want to get the information from the paragraph : example:10:00-11:00. You can make this with checkboxes or radio buttons It is really hard to do it with paragraphs, you can also make it with <select> option and get the values the same way you did for the name and surname

Comment: Is it not possible to get information from the div elements byClassName? I just do not understand how to apply it to work correctly. That is, everything was displayed in one alert

Comment: function myFunction() {
      if(this.className != "selected" && this.className != "reserved") {
                  this.className = "selected";
                  //alert ("Selekted !");
            } else if (this.className == "selected" && this.className != "reserved") {
                   this.className = "selected";
                   var r = confirm("You have booked time. If you change your mind click 'cancel'!");

Comment: if (r == true) {
                         alert("Thank you");
                         this.className = "selected";
                } else {
                       this.className = "reserved";
                       alert("You canceled your reservation!");
                 }}

Comment: I think you have a problem when you access the className, try accessing it in a different way, for example 
this.getAttribute("class")=="selected"